# Kotlin extract letters and keep only numbers in a String

Tags: kotlin, extract

I have a string that is "M456456" for example, and i need to keep only the numbers. So the ouput has to be "456456"

How can i achieve this in Kotlin?

Comment: You can use a regular expression and replace the match by an empty string.

Answer (score 13):

```kotlin
"M456456".filter(Char::isDigit)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
"M456456".filter {it in '0'..'9'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex replacement and remove all non digit characters:

```kotlin
val regex = """[^0-9]""".toRegex()
val input = "M456456"
val output = regex.replace(input, "")
println(output)  // 456456
```